# add alternatively class odd

Tags: php, html

i need to add a class "odd"  alternatively like the example:

```
<tr>
    <li></li>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
    <li></li>
</tr>
<tr>
    <li></li>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
    <li></li>
</tr>
```

first tr add the class "odd", next have no class, next again class "odd", next no class.

the code:

```
<?php
    echo "
    <div class=\"table-blue\">
        <h4>Preços de domínios</h4>
        <table class=\"table\">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><b>Extenção</b></th>
                    <th><b>1 Ano</b></th>
                    <th><b>2 Anos</b></th>
                    <th><b>3 Anos</b></th>
                    <th><b>5 Anos</b></th>
                    <th><b>10 Anos</b></th>
                    <th style=\"text-align: center;\"><b>Acção</b></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>";
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                echo "
                    <tr class=\"odd\">
                        <td><b>".$row['extension']."</b></td>
                        <td>" . ($row['msetupfee'] =='-1.00' ? '<i>N/D</i>' : $row['msetupfee'] . " " . $row['curprefix']) . "</td>
                                    <td>" . ($row['qsetupfee'] =='-1.00' ? '<i>N/D</i>' : $row['qsetupfee'] . " " . $row['curprefix']) . "</td>
                                    <td>" . ($row['ssetupfee'] =='-1.00' ? '<i>N/D</i>' : $row['ssetupfee'] . " " . $row['curprefix']) . "</td>
                                    <td>" . ($row['bsetupfee'] =='-1.00' ? '<i>N/D</i>' : $row['bsetupfee'] . " " . $row['curprefix']) . "</td>
                                    <td>" . ($row['biennially'] =='-1.00' ? '<i>N/D</i>' : $row['biennially'] . " " . $row['curprefix']) . "</td>
                                    <td style=\" width: 100px;\"><a class=\"button small blue\" href=\"http://nova-data.eu/whmcs/cart.php?a=add&domain=register&tld=".$row['extension']."\" target=\"_blank\">Comprar</a></td>
                                </tr>
                                ";
                        ?>
```

Can someone help my please?

Comment: you could style it without a class.

Comment: Use a counter in your while loop.

Comment: He is refering to this : http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to count rows and when you have odd row, add a class to table row. So:

```
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<tr' . ($i % 2 == 1 ? ' class="odd"' : '') . '>';
        echo '<td>...';
        // other TDs
    echo '</tr>';

    $i++;
}
```

If you need this class to set styles only, you can works without this classname directly in CSS:

```
tr:nth-child(2n+1) {/* style for odd rows */}
```

OR

```
tr:nth-child(odd) {/* style for odd rows */}
```

Comment: +1 for the use of modulo. Btw nth-child not support by IE < 9.

Comment: @Debflav: yes, isn't supported, but zebra table is one of things IE8- users can live without.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
echo "
<div class=\"table-blue\">
    <h4>Preços de domínios</h4>
    <table class=\"table\">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><b>Extenção</b></th>
                <th><b>1 Ano</b></th>
                <th><b>2 Anos</b></th>
                <th><b>3 Anos</b></th>
                <th><b>5 Anos</b></th>
                <th><b>10 Anos</b></th>
                <th style=\"text-align: center;\"><b>Acção</b></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>";
        $x=0;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
          $x++;
          if ($x % 2 == 0) {
            $class = 'odd';
          }else{
            $class = '';
          }
            echo "
                <tr class='".$class."'>
                    <td><b>".$row['extension']."</b></td>
                    <td>" . ($row['msetupfee'] =='-1.00' ? '<i>N/D</i>' : $row['msetupfee'] . " " . $row['curprefix']) . "</td>
                                <td>" . ($row['qsetupfee'] =='-1.00' ? '<i>N/D</i>' : $row['qsetupfee'] . " " . $row['curprefix']) . "</td>
                                <td>" . ($row['ssetupfee'] =='-1.00' ? '<i>N/D</i>' : $row['ssetupfee'] . " " . $row['curprefix']) . "</td>
                                <td>" . ($row['bsetupfee'] =='-1.00' ? '<i>N/D</i>' : $row['bsetupfee'] . " " . $row['curprefix']) . "</td>
                                <td>" . ($row['biennially'] =='-1.00' ? '<i>N/D</i>' : $row['biennially'] . " " . $row['curprefix']) . "</td>
                                <td style=\" width: 100px;\"><a class=\"button small blue\" href=\"http://nova-data.eu/whmcs/cart.php?a=add&domain=register&tld=".$row['extension']."\" target=\"_blank\">Comprar</a></td>
                            </tr>
                            ";
                    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $i=0;
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      $i++;
      if ($i % 2 == 0) {
          echo "<tr class=\"even\">\n";
      } else {
          echo "<tr class=\"odd\">\n";
      }
      //<TD> etc..
```